# Using Unattended-Upgrades to update security packages without user interaction

Tags: apt, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

Using unattended-upgrades to install security packages. Which runs daily.
However I've noticed for the last week or so that security packages haven't been installed.
After some investigation I found that these updates require user interaction. (IE they have an interactive prompt during update)

How can I get  unattended-upgrades to assume no on these prompts ?

I tried using APT::GET::ASSUME-NO but that doesn't appear to work.

Seems there has to be some way to get around this as I manage many servers and updating security for each one would be rather time consuming.

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file looks as so

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
      "origin=${distro_id},archive=${distro_codename}";
      "origin=${distro_id},archive=${distro_codename}-security";
  };

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Upon logging in I see

```
22 updates are security updates.
```

EDIT:
Running Ubuntu-Server 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1035-aws x86_64)

The package that is requires interaction during update is php7.0-fpm.

Adding

```
DPkg::Options {
        "--force-confold";
        "--force-confdef";
};
```

does appear to stop conffile prompts. However running `sudo unattended-upgrades -d` gives me the message.

```
dpkg is configured not to cause conffile prompts
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

So maybe this is just something I will have to deal with. But I am hoping someone out there has found a way around this.

We manage 100's of servers. So as you can imagine doing this manually on each one would be rather time consuming.

Comment: Which version of Linux? Is it a desktop or a server? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1307142/edit) and add the new information in the question.

Comment: Updated to include details to the version. and OS type (Server) not Desktop

Comment: If it requires interaction, then there's a reason. Don't try to outsmart apt's question; simply answer it.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. That's fine if this was one or two servers. But to manually do it across hundreds of servers isn't really a simply "answer it" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What question is triggering the user-interaction?

I include these settings in my apt configuration for `unattended-upgrades`.  They will answer `dpkg` prompts for configuration file changes

```
DPkg::Options {
        "--force-confold";
        "--force-confdef";
};
```

More information at https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.automatic-upgrades.html

**EDIT**

I don't know how the `update-notifier` code differentiates between security updates and other updates.  The MOTD output may use different criteria than `unattended-upgrades`.

If you are looking specifically at `php7.0-fpm`, check the output of `apt-cache policy php7.0-fpm`.  That will tell you what the candidate version is and what repository the version comes from.

One of the potential sources of confusion with `unattended-upgrades` is the default config does **not** install updates from the `updates` repository.  Here is another apt config I use to install updates from the `updates` repository (as well as the ESM repositories).

```
#clear Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins;
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-updates";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-security";
};
```

The package `php7.0-fpm` indicates another potential problem.  You say you are using **18.04.4**, but that package only exists in the official repositories for **16.04**.  If you installed this from an unofficial repository, then `unattended-upgrades` won't update the package unless the `Origins-Pattern` matches it.

Comment: php7.0-fpm was the package that was triggering the user-interaction.
It looks like that setting will help in some cases. However after updating my conf file for unattended-upgrades, and then manually triggering unattended-upgrades I still don't get the updates. But I do see this "dpkg is configured not to cause conffile prompts
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals" So it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I added a couple more tips based on the info provided in your edit