# Is running `apt upgrade` redundant (for security) with the default unattended-upgrades config?

Tags: apt, server, unattended-upgrades

I'd just like to confirm if I correctly understand the implications of the relationship between the `-security` and `-updates` archives (as discussed in [Are security.ubuntu.com updates eventually merged into normal updates?](https://askubuntu.com/q/185317) and the linked [Ubuntu Wiki Security FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ)).

I run Ubuntu Server instances exposed to the internet, and I've always rebooted them periodically to ensure that all the security updates take effect. Before doing so, I also run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. I'm not actually interested in bug fixes; I've only been running `apt upgrade` because I thought it's also needed for security.

The links above however seem to say that this is actually redundant from a security POV. So **my main question is, am I correct that with a default unattended-upgrades setup, I do not actually need to manually run `apt upgrade`, and that periodically restarting processes or rebooting the server is sufficient to keep my system software patched?** (I understand that user applications are a different concern, that I also need to setup a firewall etc.; I'm only asking about Ubuntu-provided software security patching.)

By the way, by default config, I mean that my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` has these lines at the top (comments removed):

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
};
```

As a secondary question: regarding this statement:

> Anything built for "-security" is built on top of which ever version of a package is newest between "-updates" and "-security", so that nothing in "-security" will introduce bug regressions.

Does this mean that even if I never manually run `sudo apt upgrade` (which as I understand pulls from the `-updates` archive unlike the default unattended-upgrades setup), my packages will actually get bugfixes from `-updates` via automatically installed `-security` patches? This is partly where my question title comes from: for packages that receive security patches after `-updates` bugfixes (not true for all packages, admittedly), this seems to imply that `-updates` is in a limited sense redundant, because the non-security bugfixes still end up in systems through just security updates.

Comment: Counter: https://askubuntu.com/q/1307142/158442

Comment: "*the non-security bugfixes still end up in systems through just security updates.*" Only if CVE mitigations are frequent, or occur regularly soon after bugfixes. Such coincidences are not reliable.

Comment: @muru thanks for the link. It seems to be an edge case I haven't encountered yet (again because I've always done `apt upgrade`), but does it mean the answer to my main question is no? That I really should also do `apt upgrade` manually, periodically?

Comment: My takeaway is rather that you should be checking the logs of unattended upgrades periodically. If these really are internet-facing servers, then you presumably have some sort of monitoring system in place? Then have unattended upgrades be part of that monitoring too, and show summaries of what it did. Then you will know if anything were held back, and take action (`apt upgrade` or otherwise) only if needed.

Comment: @muru ah, that sounds like the correct approach to my main concern. Thank you. I'd accept/upvote this if it were an answer (and once I have enough site reputation).

Answer (score 1):

The original concept:

`<release>`: The original packages on release day in all pockets.
`<release>-security`: Patched packages that mitigate CVEs [mostly in the Main pocket]. Uploaded by the Ubuntu Security Team
`<release>-updates`: Patched packages that fix bugs in all pockets. Uploaded by various teams, including community [MOTUs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU).

You can see that there are several criteria for -security vs -updates:

- If the patch is for a bugfix vs a CVE mitigation
- Which pocket of the Ubuntu repositories
- Who did the upload

If you stick to stock Ubuntu and Main packages, then 99% of your CVE mitigations will come from the Ubuntu Security Team via -security. And 99% of your non-security bugfixes will come through -updates.

When you add in Universe and Multiverse packages, then you are getting CVE mitigations from different sources. It's quite possible for a CVE Mitigation in a Universe or Multiverse package to get uploaded by a MOTU to -updates.

And, of course, Snaps avoid the complexity by simply not differentiating, not using different pockets, and not going through different teams.